# Tuning my Ubuntu installation

Tags: performance

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and i'm interested in hearing a few tips on how to improve performance and tune my system to be faster. Any articles or links on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very broad question. It would be easier to answer if you told us exactly what you want to improve the performance of.

Comment: This is tough because personal environments are usually already customized, so apples-to-apples comparisons are hard to come by.  To start, you might indicate what your system is (Ubuntu version, hardware) and even include a relevant benchmark for your current set-up?

Comment: By sheer coincidence I had the same question... Vinny any progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't get me wrong, but don't try to optimise something if you don't even know where to start or if you don't have a specific issue.

Seriously, Ubuntu is out of the box already very good compiled, there's hardly anything to do which would not require in-depth knowledge of the system (except changes for special hardware, like SSDs). If you'd want a better system performance, you'd need to re-compile and customise the kernel. If you'd want to speed up the boot, you'd have to mess GRUB2 and upstart.

Concentrate on the important things, f.e. customisation of your work environment. Have a look at [devils pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/), [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) and similar tools. And start messing with the system if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Some links that could be helpful:

- http://www.zolved.com/synapse/view_content/28224/How_to_tune_your_Ubuntu_PC_for_faster_performance_
- http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/alternative-to-200-lines-kernel-patch.html

Comment: Also try: http://techstroke.com/optimize-ubuntu-for-better-performance-speed-up-ubuntu-10-04.html (should also work for 10.10)

Comment: To your first link, you'll most likely never feel the first two changes on a 'normal' system (2 Cores, 2Gib RAM). The last one (concurrency boot) on the other hand, sounds very interesting.